# template toolkit hash values not printing and keys not sorting numerically

Tags: template-toolkit

starting with a hash ref....

```
my $my_hash = {};
```

building the hash in a loop...

```
push(@tmp_arr,$val1);
push(@tmp_arr,$val2);
$my_hash->{$index} = \@tmp_arr;
```

the elements for any key can be access fine as   $my_hash->{$index}[0]

I am passing a hash like this:

```
my $vars = {
   myhash => $my_hash                
};
```

PROBLEM 1: trying to print like this, it prints the index correctly but does not print any values.... i am confused why?

```
[%- FOREACH index IN myhash.keys.sort -%]
    <tt>index number=[%index%]  value_1=[%myhash.$index.0%]  value_2=[%myhash.$index.1%]<tt>
[% END -%]
```

PROBLEM 2: the sort is not sorting numerically, so i get 1,10,11,12.... 2,20,21.....

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is probably down to confusion over whether $index refers to array position or a hash-key. I'd suspect it is probably assuming that a numeric key belongs to an array.

The [vmethod `item()`](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_item) is often a useful work-around when you have hash-keys that can be confused with other vmethods. I would try the following:

```
<tt>index number=[%index%]  value_1=[%myhash.item(index).0%]
    value_2=[%myhash.item(index).1%]
</tt>
```

The second problem is [easily sorted](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_sort_nsort) (if you'll pardon the pun):

```
[%- FOREACH index IN myhash.keys.nsort -%]
```

*By the way, there's another open `<tt>` tag at the end of your example, but I assume it's right (a closing `</tt>`) in your original code.*